# How to detect IIS Express version?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version, updates, iis-express, asp.net-4.5

I have found that our ASP.NET application runs differently on different machines in IIS Express. All have VS 2012, .Net 4.5 and Integrated mode. But some has VS 2012 Update 1, some not.

How do I find IIS Express version?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Browse to `"C:\Program Files\IIS Express"`, select the file `iisexpress.exe`, press Alt+Enter to open the properties dialog, click on the Details tab and read the product version.

Comment: If you are scripting a check on the version, or would just prefer that approach, you can get the registry entry with `Get-ChildItem -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IISExpress`; this will output the name of the child item, which will be the {major.minor} version, and the properties under that are shown, which will have the full version number.

Answer (score 10):

`HttpRuntime.IISVersion` will give you the major and minor version of IIS (e.g., *8.0*).

`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileVersionInfo` will give you much more information, including the file version and build flavor (e.g., *8.0.8418.0 (winmain(eokim).120521-1311)*).

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to get the version without programming? Where IIS Express exe file is located?

Comment: IIS Express can be xcopy-deployed, so you don't really know which version will be used to run you until you're actually running.  For full IIS, you could check the operating system version.

Comment: Our customers always use IIS Express provided with Visual Studio. We need the IIS Express version only to understand what is causing variations in behavior (IIS Express or something else). I can not include detection code in the product until we understand the issue. Now we can detect IIS Express version only manually, looking at file version, About dialog, etc. Anyway thank you for your answer, it will be helpful for future.