# Changes to a file require two page refreshes

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

After updating a file, when running on my dev machine, I need to refresh my browser twice in order to see the changes.

How do I see the changes upon the first refresh?

Its not the browser's cache. It doesn't happen with the same browser on the live site. Server is IIS Express.

Comment: Depends on the Internet Browser, for example Internet Explorer has a really annoying setting in it's `Internet Settings` underneath `Browser History` -> `Settings` -> `Check for newer versions of stored pages` that by default is set to `Automatic` *(which in my experience behaves erratically and can really scupper you when in development)*. I recommend setting this to `Every time I visit a webpage` to stop the weird caching behaviour. Other things to check, make sure the IIS server is not caching the ASP output which vary between IIS versions and try explicitly setting `Cache-Control` headers.

Comment: Another method for doing this is to append a random number or the current time to your address, like so: http://www.example.com/?a=7389574 or http://www.example.com/?t=20160128T090327

Comment: Its not the cache. It doesn't happen with the same browser on the live site.

Comment: I've been having this problem with IIS Express. See this question, though the answers have not helped me yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673523/iis-express-overly-caching-classic-asp-pages

Answer (score 0):

You can force your browser to empty its cache by using ctrl+f5